# PANDAS - How do I change the size and colors of a bar?

Tags: python, pandas, graph

I want to increase the **size of this bar**, and to **change the color** of number 2 (FEB) or 12 (DES), because they are too similar.

[image]

How can I do it?

THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the next time please add your code not as an image! I'm using this small dict:

```py
posts_created = {
    1: {2011: 0, 2012: 92, 2013: 129},
    2: {2011: 0, 2012: 72, 2013: 99},
}
```

### Size

As pandas is using matplotlib you can take a look to the matplotlib [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html).

```py
pd.DataFrame(posts_created).plot.bar(width=0.8)
```

[image]

### Color

You can specifiy the color options for each columns like this (see [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html)):

```py
pd.DataFrame(posts_created).plot.bar(color={1: "red", 2: "blue"})
```

[image]